# Como puedo buscar a un usuario creado y luego modificar sus datos según este código

Tags: c#

Tengo problemas, tengo que generar un buscador al momento de crear el usuario, pero las veces que lo e intentado no me genera nada, solo me activa el rut, por eso no puse el buscador, de ante mano gracias si alguien me ayuda por favor.

```
//capa usuario

public class Usuario
{
    private string _IdUsuario;
    private string _Rut;
    private string _NombreCompleto;
    private int _Telefono;
    private string _Correo;

    //constructor hecho
    //getter y setter hechos

}

//capa para llamar instancia del cmt
public string MetodoCMT()
{
    try
    {
        return obNombreUsuarioDA.MetodoCMT();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
        return null;
    }
}

//capa para conectar al CMT
public class ConectarCMT
{
    static public String _userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USER_CRM"];
    static public String _password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PASS_CRM"];
    static public string _deviceId = "";
    static public string _devicePass = "";
    static public String organizationUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL_CRM"];

    static public OrganizationServiceProxy CreateOrganization()
    {
        ClientCredentials cred1 = new ClientCredentials();
        cred1.UserName.UserName = _userName;
        cred1.UserName.Password = _password;
        ClientCredentials cred2 = new ClientCredentials();
        cred2.UserName.UserName = _deviceId;
        cred2.UserName.Password = _devicePass;
        OrganizationServiceProxy obj;
        if (_deviceId.Length > 0)
            obj = new OrganizationServiceProxy(
            new Uri(organizationUri),
            null,
            cred1,
            cred2);
        else
            obj = new OrganizationServiceProxy(
           new Uri(organizationUri),
           null,
           cred1,
           null);
        obj.EnableProxyTypes();

        return obj;

    }
}

//Capa de datos
public static bool MetodoAgregarCRM(Usuario us)
{
    IOrganizationService servicio;
    servicio = ConectarCMT.CreateOrganization();
    try
    {
        Account ac = new Account();
        ac.zth_idn = us.Rut;
        ac.Name = us.NombreCompleto;
        ac.Telephone1 = us.Telefono.ToString();
        ac.EMailAddress1 = us.Correo;
        servicio.Create(ac);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }

}
//capa de vista
protected void btnAgregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Usuario us = new Usuario();
        us.Rut = txtRut.Text;
        us.NombreCompleto = txtNombreCompleto.Text;
        us.Telefono = int.Parse(txtTelefono.Text);
        us.Correo = txtCorreo.Text;
        bool resp = NombreUsuarioDA.MetodoAgregarCMT(us);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message); ;
    }

    Limpiar();

}

private void Limpiar()
{
    txtRut.Text = "";
    txtNombreCompleto.Text = "";
    txtTelefono.Text = "";
    txtCorreo.Text = "";
}
```

---

```
private static List<Usuario> user = new List<Usuario>();

public static List<Usuario> ObtenerUsuario() 
{ 
    return user; 
} 

public static Usuario Buscar(string rut) 
{ 
    IOrganizationService servicio; 
    servicio = ConectarCRM.CreateOrganization(); 
    Usuario obj = null; 
    foreach (Usuario xx in user) 
    { 
        if (xx.Rut.Equals(rut)) 
        { 
            obj = xx; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    return obj; 
}
```

---

```
Usuario us = new Usuario(); 
string rut; 
rut = txtRutB.Text; 
txtNomCompletoB.Text = ""; 
foreach (Usuario xx in NombreUsuarioDA.ObtenerUsuario()) 
{ 
    if (xx.Rut.Equals(rut)) 
    { 
        txtNomCompletoB.Text += x.NombreCompleto.ToString(); 
        txtTelefonoB.Text += xx.Telefono.ToString(); 
        txtCorreoB.Text += xx.Correo.ToString(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        lblConsulta.Text = "Usuario no existe"; 
    } 
    bool resp = NombreUsuarioDA.Buscar(us); 
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No se entiende mucho lo que necesitas, podrias ser mas claro de donde tenes el problema?

Comment: lo que pasa, que tengo un problema con este codigo, al crear una persona lo hace todo bien, pero cuando quiero buscar a la personada creada, no me busca por el rut, me sale que la persona no esta encontrada y solo me rellena el rut,

Comment: private static List<Usuario> user = new List<Usuario>();
        public static List<Usuario> ObtenerUsuario()
        {
            return user;
        }
        public static Usuario Buscar(string rut)
        {
            IOrganizationService servicio;
            servicio = ConectarCRM.CreateOrganization();
            Usuario obj = null;
            foreach (Usuario xx in user)
            {
                if (xx.Rut.Equals(rut))
                {
                    obj = xx;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return obj;
       }

Comment: Lee los enlaces que te pase. Edita tu pregunta usando el boton [edit] y agrega eso, que es donde tenes el problema a tu pregunta.

Comment: Usuario us = new Usuario();
            string rut; rut = txtRutB.Text; txtNomCompletoB.Text = ""; foreach (Usuario xx in NombreUsuarioDA.ObtenerUsuario())
            { if (xx.Rut.Equals(rut)) { txtNomCompletoB.Text += x.NombreCompleto.ToString();   txtTelefonoB.Text += xx.Telefono.ToString();
                    txtCorreoB.Text += xx.Correo.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblConsulta.Text = "Usuario no existe";
                }
                bool resp = NombreUsuarioDA.Buscar(us);
            }

Comment: El codigo en comenatarios no se entiende. Edita tu pregunta y agregalo donde corresponde, con la explicacion del problema.

Comment: no pongas codigo como comentario es imposible leerlo, edite la pregunta y puse el codigo

Comment: @LeandroTuttini gracias por hacerlo, pero esta bueno que lo hagan los propios usuarios, si no, no aprenden mas!!.. igual a la pregunta le falta la explicacion del problema...

Comment: consulta, de donde salen los datos de la linea, private static List<Usuario> user = new List<Usuario>(); ? quien carga esa lista?